# Как делать запрос с сервера на сайт и проходить авторизацию?

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Делаю запрос на сайт с авторизацией через следующее:

```
file_get_contents("{ссылка}");
```

Но,ясное дело, меня не пускает, как я могу в таком случае логиниться?

Comment: Зависит от сайта и авторизации. Обычно в подобных случаях используют curl, заходят на страницу авторизации, авторизовываются, сохраняют куки и подставляют в последующих запросах.

Comment: @ A K а куки сохранять в виде .txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от сайта и авторизации. Обычно в подобных случаях используют curl, заходят на страницу авторизации, авторизовываются, сохраняют куки и подставляют в последующих запросах.

> а куки сохранять в виде .txt?

Это как вам нравится, да и от задачи зависит.

Если у вас задача по крону запускается раз в сутки и после авторизации качает одну страницу - то можете не сохранять никуда, просто в переменной будет жить.

А если у вас после старта скрипта нужно собрать десяток-другой страниц -- то лучше куда-нибудь сохранить. Куда - дело вкуса. Можно в базу, можно в файл, можно никуда не сохранять, а в случае если скрипт упадёт на половине обработанных страниц - то при рестарте заново получить куку.

PS Ваш вопрос достаточно общий, его вероятнее всего закроют. Полистайте stackoverflow, тут таких тем полно. [[php] curl авторизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+curl+%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)